# Path for Flink state.checkpoints.dir in docker-compose in Windows 10 environment

Tags: windows, docker, apache-flink, checkpoint

I have Windows 10 OS, docker-compose and want to work with Apache Flink tutorial Playground, docker-compose starting correctly [starting docker-compose](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/try-flink/flink-operations-playground.html#observing-failure--recovery) but after several minutes of work,
Apache Flink has to create checkpoints, but there is some problem with access to the file system.

Exception:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Could not finalize the pending checkpoint 104. Failure reason: Failure to finalize checkpoint.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.completePendingCheckpoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1216) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
…..

Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.SerializedThrowable: Mkdirs failed to create file:/tmp/flink-checkpoints-directory/d73c2f87b0d7ea6748a1913ee4b50afe/chk-104
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.create(LocalFileSystem.java:262) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.1.jar:1.12.1]
```

Could you please help me with the correct path and docker access?

```
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///tmp/flink-checkpoints-directory
state.savepoints.dir: file:///tmp/flink-savepoints-directory
```

Also I tried use full Windows path but got the same error.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux Docker containers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows Docker containers or Linux Docker containers ?

Right-click on the Docker Desktop icon to see your current configuration.

- Switch to Windows containers

OR

- Switch to Linux containers

[image: Docker for Windows]

You have to configure Flink paths according to you target Docker container type.

Note: You cannot use Windows and Linux containers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I highly recommend using WSL2 instead of WSL1. Additionally, for the volumes I've configured them as so:

```
diff --git a/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml b/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml
index 5478271..85a5fe0 100644
--- a/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml
+++ b/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml
@@ -27,7 +27,7 @@ services:
       - kafka
     volumes:
       - ./conf:/opt/flink/conf
-      - flink_data:/tmp/
+      - /tmp/:/tmp/
     environment:
       - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
   clickevent-generator:
@@ -42,7 +42,7 @@ services:
       - 8081:8081
     volumes:
       - ./conf:/opt/flink/conf
-      - flink_data:/tmp/
+      - /tmp/:/tmp/
     environment:
       - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
   taskmanager:
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@ services:
     command: "taskmanager.sh start-foreground"
     volumes:
       - ./conf:/opt/flink/conf
-      - flink_data:/tmp/
+      - /tmp/:/tmp/
     environment:
       - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
   zookeeper:
@@ -69,5 +69,3 @@ services:
     ports:
       - 9092:9092
       - 9094:9094
-volumes:
-  flink_data:
```

And I'm running everything from within a WSL2 Ubuntu distro. Follow the guide on https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/ closely to make this work for you.